# Command + T is not working in TeXShop

Tags: errors, compiling, mactex, texshop, mac

The following screen comes out when I press CMD+T in TeXShop. I am using OS X 10.11.1 El Capitan.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the preferences of TeXShop you need to make sure that the path settings are correct.  They should be:

```
/Library/TeX/texbin
```

As in the image below.

[image]